# sample time series datasets R and python

Tags: python, r, time-series

Since I am very lazy I don't want to spend time downloading datasets, loading them and perform pre-processing to test some sample functions on different timeseries. What are some sample timeseries datasets available with R and python? (which can be imported easily). For eg: there is the iris dataset (which can be easily loaded in my environment using `data(iris)`).

Comment: Maybe take a look at the Datasets package, if you are not too lazy ... https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/datasets/html/00Index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In R, per @Kabulan0lak's comment, you can choose from different "preloaded" datasets. One way to see what you currently have available in your system is to type:

```
data()
```

Since you're looking for time series data, I would suggest the `EuStockMarkets` dataset. You can either load it in your space explicitly:

```
data("EuStockMarkets")
```

or call it directly, simply typing:

```
EuStockMarkets
```

Other datasets that may interest you include:

- `LakeHuron` dataset is a single series of class `ts`.
- `JohnsonJohnson` quarterly earnings of the company Johnson  & Johnson .

Answer (score 2):

The python scikit package has access to the iris and other datasets:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/datasets/plot_iris_dataset.html
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.datasets

Also, the python statsmodels packages has a datasets module for accessing R datasets:

http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/0.6.0/datasets/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I think the Performance Analytics package includes the dataset edhec which is a good dataset in xts format to try things on:

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/PerformanceAnalytics/versions/2.0.4/topics/edhec